# Hive streaming data ingest api Invalid method name: 'get_all_functions'

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using the Hive Streaming Data Ingest API as detailed here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Streaming+Data+Ingest. In order to be able to see my version numbers my Maven declarations are as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive.hcatalog</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-hcatalog-streaming</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive.hcatalog</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-hcatalog-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have HDP 2.5.0.0-1245 installed. All services are running on a single node for testing.

I declare my connection as follows

```
public HiveProcess(String dbname, String tablename, List<String> partitionVals)
{
    hiveEP = new HiveEndPoint("thrift://" + HadoopProperties.HIVE_HOST + ":" + HadoopProperties.HIVE_THRIFT_PORT, dbname, tablename, partitionVals);
    try {
        //generate timestamp agent string to be identifiable in logs
        String agent = "tablename-";

        Date curdate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        agent = agent + format.format(curdate);
        hiveStream = hiveEP.newConnection(true, agent);
    } catch (ConnectionError|InvalidPartition|InvalidTable|PartitionCreationFailed|ImpersonationFailed|InterruptedException|UndeclaredThrowableException e) {
        log.error("HiveProcess constructor: " + e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

It successfully creates the connection so then it runs

```
public boolean processBatch(List<byte[]> toInsert) {
    try {
        StrictJsonWriter write = new StrictJsonWriter(hiveEP);
        TransactionBatch txnBatch = hiveStream.fetchTransactionBatch(toInsert.size(), write);
        //open the TransactionBatch
        txnBatch.beginNextTransaction();
        //loop through records for insertion
        for(byte[] ins: toInsert) {
            txnBatch.write(ins);
        }
        //commit batch
        txnBatch.commit();
        txnBatch.close();
        //clean up connection, we are done until next time
        hiveStream.close();
        //if we made it to here, this is a success
        return true;
    } catch (StreamingException|InterruptedException|UndeclaredThrowableException e) {
        log.error("HiveProcess processBatch " + e.getMessage());
        //clean up connection, we are done until next time
        hiveStream.close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

At this line in the source of HiveEndPoint it kicks the error
        localSession = SessionState.start(new CliSessionState(conf));

The output log looks like this

```
15:17:22.634 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://localhost:9083
15:17:22.657 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 1
15:17:22.672 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Connected to metastore.
15:17:41.306 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://localhost:9083
15:17:41.311 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 2
15:17:41.325 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Connected to metastore.
15:17:41.604 [main] WARN  hive.ql.metadata.Hive - Failed to register all functions.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'get_all_functions'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3593) ~[hive-exec-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236) ~[hive-exec-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221) [hive-exec-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366) [hive-exec-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310) [hive-exec-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290) [hive-exec-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266) [hive-exec-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:545) [hive-exec-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:513) [hive-exec-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.createPartitionIfNotExists(HiveEndPoint.java:445) [hive-hcatalog-streaming-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going wrong here and what I need to do to correct this?

Thanks!